# Capacitor 3 and VueJS, open saved file (or download)

Tags: vue.js, file, download, capacitor

I am struggling with something I thought will be simple.

Ideally I want to save my base64 file with prompt same as you get when downloading from browser, however that seems impossible with capacitor app.

So I used FileSystem, to save file on `Documents` directory, which went fine, I also can get uri file. But because there is no indicator that file was saved, I would like to at least try to open the file with native apps. I've noticed there is cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-file-opener2` but I can't seem to make it work with capacitor 3 and VueJs, without cordova.

Maybe I am overthinking it ? is there any way download file or open file with Capacitor?

For web view (not native app) I am using hidden download button, but that does not work at all in capacitor app

here is my current code

```js
Filesystem.writeFile({
    data: pdf,
    path: `${this.fileName}.pdf`,
    directory: Directory.Documents,
 }).then(() => {
    Filesystem.getUri({
    path: `${this.fileName}.pdf`,
    directory: Directory.Documents,
 }).then(res => {
  // open file here with my res.uri ?
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exakt same problem. I solved/workarounded it by using the official capacitor "Share" plugin, so the user can choose what she wants to do with the file. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/share

I did not find any other solution to show or download those privately stored files. FileOpener seems to have a lot of problems on Android and does not work either on iOS.

Comment: I did actually make FileOpener work, I am not confident in that plugin tho, seems to work for now. Share is also not ideal solution. Kind of weird, that something so crucial is not covered in capacitor

Comment: Well, Capacitor3 is only a few weeks out. Let’s hope that there will be many more official plugins that do not have to deal with old Cordova code.

Comment: this is good point, I actually didn't realized that Capacitor 3 is just released

Comment: @uneasy  How did you managed to make that work?

Comment: I've actually used that plugin `cordova-plugin-file-opener2` so write file with Capcitor plugin then open it with cordova plugin